# Where i should manage my asp.net mvc windows authntication Roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

If I use windows authentication inside an asp.net mvc web project , I will not get any membership database, unlike form based authentication . But I can still use Roles. So i have the following questions:-

1. So where are these roles managed, and how I will be assigning users to roles when using windows authentication ?
2. are these roles managed and created only inside Active directory ? and if I want to add a user to specific role, I will be doing this inside the active directory ?

so can anyone advice ?

**Edit**
Now if i understand your point well, let say that i want to restrict calling an action method to only our company admininstrators. where currently inside active directory we have a group of users named "OurCompanyAdminsitrators"

so let say i create a new asp.net mvc5 web project , and i specify to use Windows authentication , then inside my action method i wrote the following:-

```
[Authorize(Roles = "OurCompanyAdminsitrators")]
```

will asp.net mvc5 recognize the OurCompnayAdministrators user group ? or i need to do extra work for my asp.net mvc web project to be able to read and check against the active directory groups ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are many ways to approach this, 2 I can think of off the top of my head:

1. Use Active Directory to manage your roles and add users to the Active Directory groups as required. You can then access them through the users Identity in which you can get from the http context.
2. Create a separate service/component to manage the security for you where you map user credentials to roles that you define yourself completely away from AD. Obviously there is more of a time investment here and you will need to duplicate some information.

Comment: can you check my edit, as i did not understand your point very well.

Comment: Pretty much yes the name needs to be [Domain\RoleName]
I think you may find this [link](http://www.squarewidget.com/authorizationattribute-with-windows-authentication-in-mvc-4) useful

Answer (score 1):

We can use `SimpleMembership` provider. "SimpleMembership: The future of membership for ASP.NET".

http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/689801/Understanding-and-Using-Simple-Membership-Provider

http://www.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/226/Adding-ASP-NET-SimpleMembership-to-an-existing-MVC-4-application/

Edit:

We can use `SqlRoleProvider`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server

Comment: As mentioned by your 3 links SimpleMembership is used for Internet application, while my question is about windows authentication where users are exists inside active directory .. but i am not sure where the Roles will be managed , when using windows authentication

Comment: sqlRoleProvider means that i am going to store the users on a database, while using windows authentication allow me to call the users from AD automatically ...

Comment: If we use SqlRoleProvider,it'll create database with predefined tables/sps like aspnet_users,aspnet_roles to do authorization. Check  this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx